# Axios- redirect in issue

Tags: axios

I'm having trouble getting redirects to work after accepting a get request from Axios. I do know that the request is being sent and that it at least gets some response from the URL route,

when i console `response.data.redirect` it return undefined

```
const onSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    axios.get('/get/user')
        .then(function (response) {
            if (response.data.redirect == '/' || response.data.redirect == '/login' ) {
                window.location = "/login"
            } else {
              console.log(response.data)
             }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            window.location = "/login"
        })
}
```

I received status code 302 but it automatically redirects to the page without page refresh shows the redirected page on the same page in a div section.
Anyone knows how can I use interceptor with Axios such that if the status code fall in 200 series then does something else page refresh. I checked the Axios docs but there is no implementation
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this for interceptors

```
axios.interceptors.response.use(
    response => {
        return response.data;
    },
    err => {
        //return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            //err.response.status for getting error status
            // }
            throw err;
        });
    }
);
```